# Excel VBA - email subject line to include value of offset cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VB, and would appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance.

I am trying to get an email sent off when a particular cell has a certain value. For example, when Cell E3 has a value of 1 I want to send email 1, when it has a value of 2 I want to send email 2. This portion is working. I also want the subject line to be the contents of the cell 3 places to the left, i.e. when cell E3 is triggered to send an email, I want the subject line to be the contents of B3, when E4 is triggered, I want the subject to be the contents of B4. This is where I am slipping up, I have tried various offsets and range options, but I just get a blank subject line in the email. This is what I have:

```
Dim xRg As Range
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("E3:E5"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 1 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 2 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook2
        End If
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Good Day" & vbNewLine & _
              "Content Mail 1"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "xxx@mci.co.za"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook2()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Good Day" & vbNewLine & _
              "Content Mail 2"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "xxx@mci.co.za"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: See if you can capture  ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value as a temporary string before the With.. End With construct. If the string is empty, you may have a ActiveCell connection problem, or the datatype / excelsheet / workbook reference may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ActiveCell, I would add “Target” as a parameter to `Mail_small_Text_Outlook`. That way you can be sure that the cell you are referencing is the same one.

If you need to use ActiveCell (for some reason) and you’re not getting the right result, you can use something like:
`MsgBox ActiveCell.Address`
Just to double check that the cell your working with is the one you’re expecting.

I would also advise combining `Mail_small_Text_Outlook` and `Mail_small_Text_Outlook2` into one sub and adding a parameter to specify which email body you want to use. That way the code for opening Outlook and creating the actual email is only in one place, so if you need to change/debug it, you only have to do it once.

The final sub might look something like this:
`Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Target As Range, EmailBody As Integer)`.